# I am trying to write an "if then" statement. If df['time'] is in format YYYY then df['time']=df['year']. Else df['time']=df['date2']

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I am creating a code which will work over several data sets. Some data sets give me the year and some give me the month-day-year. I have code already to extract the months and days out to just years, but I need to write something which will leave the years alone if its already in the YYYY format.

```py
if df['year'] **contains four digits YYYY:
 df['year']=df['year']

else:
 df['year'] = df['monthdayyear'].astype(str).str[:10]
```

Ultimately, I would like to have only the years remaining in the format YYYY

Comment: can you provide an example of two inputs and the different outputs?

Comment: Use a regular expression?

Comment: Or just get the length -- if it's 4 characters then it's just the year.

Comment: df['year'] = np.where(condition, df['year'], df['monthdayyear'].astype(str).str[:10]`.

Comment: If the DF is internally-consistent, then you only need a `try`/`except` on the first row to determine the format before applying to the rest of the DF. You can obviously also use [`infer_datetime_format`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html)

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is what you are asking for, if it's not, comment and edit your answer with what is your expected output.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
a = {'year':[1990,1923,1904,'not4digits','not4digits',2001],'monthdayyear':[1990,1923,1904,20140901,20180305,2001]}
df = pd.DataFrame(a)
print(df)
df['year'] = np.where(len(df['year']) == 4, df['year'],df['monthdayyear'].astype(str).str[:10])
print(df)
```

Output before applying condition:

```
         year  monthdayyear
0        1990          1990
1        1923          1923
2        1904          1904
3  not4digits      20140901
4  not4digits      20180305
5        2001          2001
```

Output after applying `np.where` where the condition is not met and the values in column `year` are replaced with the values in columns `monthdayyear`:

```
       year  monthdayyear
0      1990          1990
1      1923          1923
2      1904          1904
3  20140901      20140901
4  20180305      20180305
5      2001          2001
```